# IE not working for javascript onclick event ... works in FF and Chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

When I create my javascript onclick event in my c# codebehind (asp.net 4.5 framework, VS2012), it works great in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE 11). I tried with and without the  "this" keyword:

```
lstMultipleValues.Attributes.Add("onclick", "FindSelectedItems(" + txtSelectedMLValues.ClientID + ");");

lstMultipleValues2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "FindSelectedItems(this," + txtSelectedMLValues2.ClientID + ");");
```

When I click on it ... the following pops in in the dynamic code and the error:

> Unhandled exception at line 159, column 1 in script block
>
> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'MainBody_txtSelectedMLValues'
>   is undefined

Here is the dynamic code created in VS2012:

> function onclick(event) {
>   FindSelectedItems(MainBody_txtSelectedMLValues); }

I'm sure I'm missing something simple... please have mercy and help an exhausted developer. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please share some front-end code.

Comment: Side note: it may be better to use JQuery and select element by classes than IDs in your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lstMultipleValues.Attributes.Add("onClick", "FindSelectedItems('" + txtSelectedMLValues.ClientID + "');");
```

if IE click event is only the problem then you should use onClick instead of onclick

Comment: Thanks for this... it turned out to be this, as well as a discrepancy between how IE handles javascript as opposed to other browsers. Thanks for the assist... finally got it working with a javascript IsIE() boolean function!!! painful thou....

Answer (score 1):

Your likely goal is "element ID in quotes":

```
function onclick(event) { FindSelectedItems('MainBody_txtSelectedMLValues'); }
```

So you need to wrap your ID in quotes on C# side:

```
lstMultipleValues.Attributes.Add("onClick", 
   "FindSelectedItems('" + txtSelectedMLValues.ClientID + "');");
```